# VSCode - Deploy Azure App - Task not found error

Tags: azure, visual-studio-code

I am trying to deploy my Azure Web App through Azure Web Service Extension.

When i click on 'Deploy to Web App', It gives my task not found error.

Any Suggestions?

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try to re install?

Comment: Yes, reinstalled and reloaded the workspace

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to deploy to Azure web app.

Pre-Deployment Task defined in **settings.json** at Project root folder couldn't be found. I changed the task from publish-release to publish.

settings.json (earlier)

```
{
"appService.defaultWebAppToDeploy": "None",
"appService.preDeployTask": "publish-release",
"appService.deploySubpath": "publish"
}
```

settings.json (modified)

```
{
"appService.defaultWebAppToDeploy": "None",
"appService.preDeployTask": "publish",
"appService.deploySubpath": "publish"
}
```

you may also need to check publish folder before deploying it. In my scenario, i was using a custom publish folder.